# How do I import and use quantized_matmul and quantized_biasadd operations in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, quantization

I am trying to use the quantized matmul operation in tensorflow. However I am not sure if I am doing it right. I could not find an example as to how to call the function and use it.

I know that quantized conv2D can be called as tf.nn.conv2D(), just wanted to know a similar way of calling quantized_matmul operation as well.

The class and the functions are present in tensorflow library and are documented below:

Quantized Bias Add:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/quantized-bias-add

Quantized Matmul:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/quantized-mat-mul

Thanks and Regards,
Abhinav George